# Delete list element from a linked list. Reset list element pointer after the deletion. Code from Steven Skiena book

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list

I am talking about deletion in a linked list, source is from [The Algorithm Design Manual 3rd ed - Steven Skiena](https://www.algorist.com/). These are the demo files of the code:

- https://www.algorist.com/adm-code/list-demo.c
- https://www.algorist.com/adm-code/list.h

Considering the following code, and assuming that here uses *pointer to pointer* to "simulate" a kind of reference call, we have:

```c
list *item_ahead(list *l, list *x) {
   if ((l == NULL) || (l->next == NULL)) {
      return(NULL);
   }

   if ((l->next) == x) {
      return(l);
   } else {
      return(item_ahead(l->next, x));
   }
}

void delete_list(list **l, list **x) {
   list *p;     /* item pointer */
   list *pred;  /* predecessor pointer */

   p    = *l;
   pred = item_ahead(*l, *x);

   if (pred == NULL) { /* splice out of list */
      *l = p->next;
   } else {
      pred->next = (*x)->next;
   }

   free(*x); /* free memory used by node */
}
```

Doing some opening clarifications about some parts:

Considering the function `item_ahead()`, in the following:

```
   if ((l == NULL) || (l->next == NULL)) {
      return(NULL);
   }
```

- the condition at the **left** of OR :
  is true when the list is empty, i.e. when there aren't element of type `list` to point for;
- the condition at the **right** of OR :
  is true when it comes at the last element of the list without have found the `x` you look for.

===

Looking at this portion of code:

```
   if ((l->next) == x) {
      return(l);
   } else {
      return(item_ahead(l->next, x));
   }
```

- in every recursive call, `*l` assumes always the address of the `next` list element;
- so, at last, when the element is found or not, the pointer `l` points to the element wanted or to a null (because the element is not found, or the list is empty), (however, doesn't point anymore to the head).

===

Considering now the function `delete_list()`:

```
   pred = item_ahead(*l, *x);
```

after the return, we have that `*l` and `pred` points to the same thing (element or null).

===

So, after all these premises, this is the main part I don't understand:

```
   if (pred == NULL) { /* splice out of list */
      *l = p->next;
   } ...
```

Now, `pred == NULL`, for all the implications said above, and :

1. Why, we have that, after the assign, `*l` points to the next element, i.e. to the second element of the list?

In my opinion, since `*l` still points to the element wanted or is a null pointer, we would want to "reset" it to points to the head of the list, so, I think that it would be written instead as `*l = p`.

And also, I have the following questions:

2. What is the meaning of the phrase in the code: "splice out of list"?
3. And why there is the need to "reset" `*l`, since it is not used anymore?

Please, can you help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was reading, and I found this:

```
void insert_list(list **l, item_type x) {
    list *p;    /* temporary pointer */

    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
}
```

Let's see, `*l` will be always the last node added. `p->next` will save the predecessor to `*l`.
With that premise we can answer to your first question:

> 1. Why, we have that, after the assign, *l points to the next element, i.e. to the second element of the list?

Because the current node is the target, that is, the last inserted node. After the assign, `*l` points to the preceding list. Also remember, this linked-list is in **descending order** (the last node is the head).

> In my opinion, since *l still points to the element wanted or is a null pointer, we would want to "reset" it to points to the head of the list, so, I think that it would be written instead as *l = p.

You do that when you're working in **ascending order** (the first node inserted is the head). But in this case, `*l` is `x` and it does mean to get rid of `x` you just need to set head to the preceding list (`p->next`).

> 2. What is the meaning of the phrase in the code: "splice out of list"?

The target to delete (`x`) doesn't have an ahead item (`x` is the last inserted node) so you don't need to do `pred->next = (*x)->next`. Then your out of list (no ahead item to do that).

> 3. And why there is the need to "reset" *l, since it is not used anymore?

Not used anymore? It is used! `*l` saves your last added node. From there you can go through the entire list. And you reset it to the preceding list (p->next) because the current node is the target to delete.

I think this' a good reference: [linked-list-good-taste](https://github.com/mkirchner/linked-list-good-taste)

This' my first answer here. I hope I've helped you :D.

Comment: better use objects not types in sizeof `p = malloc(sizeof(list));` -> `p = malloc(sizeof(*p));`

Comment: I just quoted that snippet from the original source code: https://www.algorist.com/adm-code/list-demo.c And as you said is better.

Comment: @JoseS.Daniel nope. In `insert_list()`, `*l` points to the head of the list. So the next of the new item points the head element, and then the head points to the new item.

Comment: @JB-Franco Nope, `*l` will be always the new node added. And the next of this node will point to the old value of `*l`. Let's see, you create a node `a`, you set `a`'s next to `a->next = *l`, here's the hint, `*l = a` the new head will be a; the old value of head will be saved in `a->next` as we did before. In conclusion, your new node will be the head, the previous value of head will be in the new node's next.

Comment: @JoseS.Daniel I think that I don't fully understand in what way `item_ahead()` handles the case when the x exists and it is the very first item of the list, i.e. when it doesn't have any predecessor, like in this example, where the numbers represent the order of inserting: l -> 3x -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL

Comment: @JB-Franco It's easy! Check this conditional `if ((l == NULL) || (l->next == NULL))` you will get `NULL`. Are `l` or `l->next` a non-null pointer? If yes, do stuff; otherwise return `NULL` just that.

Comment: @JoseS.Daniel so does it covers all three cases? 1) when the list is empty, 2) when the searched element is not present, 3) when the searched element exists AND it is in the first position (without any predecessor).

Comment: @JoseS.Daniel I am studying the same book and I found this question while searching on the web for clarifications. As you can see in `list-demo.c`, Skiena first checks whether the element is present in list, and he calls `delete_list` only if he already knows that the element is present. You actually have just one case: `item_ahead` could return NULL only if the element is present and in first position.

Answer (score 1):

> pred = item_ahead(*l, *x)

> after the return, we have that *l and pred points to the same thing (element or null).

`pred` and `*l` don't point to the same thing, `*l` still point to the head

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `list-demo.c`, Skiena first checks whether the element is present in list, and he calls `delete_list` only if he already knows that the element is present.
You actually have just one case: `item_ahead` could return NULL only if the element is present and in first position.

In the recursive calls inside `item_ahead`, `l` stays the same. He just recursively calls `item_ahead` passing l's next pointer, and then the pointer next to l's next pointer, and so on.

After `pred = item_ahead(*l, *x);` inside `delete_item`,
`*l` and `pred` don't point to the same "thing".
In fact, he passed the pointer to `item_ahead` by value (it's C, after all). Even if he had made changes to the pointer itself internally to the function, and he had not, they would not have been maintained externally. If you want to change the pointer itself, you must pass a pointer to a pointer in C, as in `delete_item`. If you pass a pointer by value, you could only change the value the pointer point to, but he does not even make any change of this kind.

He can change the actual pointer `*l` inside `delete_item`, since it passes a pointer to a pointer. In this function, the instruction
`*l = p->next;` splices out the first element. It means that it cuts off the first element and replaces it with his next one.

I hope I was clear, it is my first answer on stackoverflow.